# Ios Swift : Add Message Tone and Vibration when notification received

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, ringtone, vibration

### Using IOS 9 and Swift 2

I have written a function to call Notification when needed.

How do i add Msg Tone and Vibration when notification received :

```
func getNotification(message:String)
{
    let curentSeting = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()

    if(curentSeting!.types == .None)
    {
        let newSeting = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(newSeting)
    }

    let nfnVar = UILocalNotification()
    nfnVar.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)
    nfnVar.alertBody = message
    nfnVar.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    nfnVar.userInfo = ["NamKey":"NamVey"]
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(nfnVar)
}
```

Comment: Tip: if you want people to even *read* your code I suggest two changes: do not, ever, use compressed/mangled variables names - things like "ChkNfnStgVar" are horrible and unreadable. And do use lowerCamelCase for variables and properties. It's a very little effort for you but it makes all the difference for the others. :)

Comment: Eric, I have modified the code and changed the variables as ur suggestion.
Kindly let me know if its the right way. I am trying to learn all by myself. So only u ppl are my tutors. 
Also help me with the question.

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, sorry, I would have posted one otherwise. :) // That's great that you're trying to improve your variable naming. Congrats! A few suggestions: methods *do* so most of the time they'll be verbs; properties *store* so they would be descriptive nouns; avoid including the type in the name; don't abbreviate; stay simple. Like, your method could be `postNotification` with a parameter of `message`. And `checkNfnSetingVar` could be `settings`. Etc. Those are yours to choose, but they always should follow the standard namings.

Comment: Hope it feels more easy to read now...

Comment: Yes, it is easier to read and to understand with complete and meaningful naming. Thanks for editing.